# Text classification with IMDB dataset get_word_index error, how to change the path

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As I am behind a proxy, I cannot access the IMDB dataset directly, so I saved the complete package in:

```
C:\Users\...\.keras\datasets\imdb.npz
```

I can successfully load the following command:

```
# save np.load
np_load_old = np.load
# modify the default parameters of np.load
np.load = lambda *a,**k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)
imdb = keras.datasets.imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
# restore np.load for future normal usage
np.load = np_load_old
```

Where I have the train and test data.

When I want to proceed with [basic text classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification), I have to get the word index:

```
word_index = imdb.get_word_index()
```

I (again) get the error:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/imdb_word_index.json: None -- [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

How can I avoid this?

I understand that I can adjust the path:

```
word_index = imdb.get_word_index(path='imdb_word_index.json')
```

But what is the right path in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, same drill, download the file at https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/imdb_word_index.json and put it inside `C:\Users\<your_username>\.keras\datasets` and then use `get_word_index` as normal.

Comment: so everytime I have a new get_data or load_data, i probably have a new file?

Comment: @PV8 No, these are different files, one for the data and another for the word index.

Comment: yes, so everytime I have a new file I have to download it into datasets.